# android- load gif animation in webview

Tags: android, animation, webview

I am displaying a gif file in `WebView`.

[image]

This gif is visible until my webpage finishes loading.

I am doing it in the following ways:

### 1st Method: Loading gif in Webview

I have put `loading.gif` in the `asset` folder.

**xml:**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

**Java:**

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            WebView loading = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            loading.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/loading.GIF");
            loading.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            WebView loading = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });
```

### 2nd Method: Loading gif frames in ImageView

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="50" />
    etc...
</animation-list>
```

**Java:**

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.movie);
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
anim.start();
```

But the animation is not smooth in both cases. Its better in the 2nd method though. I just want to know if there is any way to achieve the same effect without a gif? If thats not possible then, I want to know if the gif will be of same size in all pixel densities. As the dimension of gif file is in `px` and not in `dp`.

Comment: What have you used to load the gif images??? What do you think about the Glide Google library...Which is the better approach for gif Webview OR Glide?

Comment: You don´t need to load frames just load the animated gif inside the WebView or ImageView, i´ve added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of

#### How to load the gif into a `WebView`

Create the html with the address to the .gif file:

```
<html style="margin: 0;">
<body style="margin: 0;">
<img src="https://..../myimage.gif" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

store this file into the assets directory:

[image]

The load this html into the `WebView` of your application:

```
    WebView webView =  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/webpage_gif.html");
```

---

Heres is a [**complete example with two options (using WebView or ImageView) to load an animated gif**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-animated-Gifs).

[image]